# Withdraw from atm using PayPal debit card

Tags: paypal, withdrawal, atm

If i use my PayPal debit card at an atm and i dont have enough money in my PayPal account to withdraw the said amount will it use my linked debit card to withdraw the rest?

Answer (score 0):

With ATMs in Australia (and, I presume, across the world), you need to pick a specific account to withdraw from. This also allows you to check the balance of that account.

So if you don’t have enough in one account, the system should not automatically deduct the balance from another account on the basis of the ATM withdrawal ‘request’.

Exceptions are:

- for ‘travel’ cards with multiple currencies loaded, you may be able to arrange for an automatic conversion from a different ‘wallet’ within that account to the currency withdrawn; and
- if you have an overdraft arrangement in place, you may be able to draw on that credit, with repayment by agreement from a different account.

Neither of these is an automatic ‘top-up’ withdrawal from an account you didn’t choose at the ATM.

Comment: I know in the UK I never got asked which account to draw from when using an ATM. In the US I get asked quite frequently, usually with a list of accounts I don't even have, no clue what would happen if I selected them.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/bundle/fees) page on PayPal Cash Card, Direct Deposit, and Cash Load:

**Declined transactions and overdraft fees**

```
All Fees                    Amount    Details
Spending declines due       $0         We will only authorize purchases   
to insufficient funds                 when you have sufficient funds 
                                      in your balance.
ATM withdrawal declines     $0         We will only authorize ATM withdrawals 
due to insufficient funds             when you have sufficient funds in your 
                                      balance.
```